# Editable Grid MVVM Entity Framework example application

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am looking for a good example of a MVVM application that uses a editable grid to display entities. I already tried to bind a grid to a ObservableCollection of entities which worked without any problems. The only thing that I wanted to do is to bind a save button in a way that it is disabled when there are validation errors in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like that :

```
    class MyCustomCommand : ICommand
    {
        public MyCustomCommand(ObservableCollection<object> collection)
        {
            collection.CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
                        CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
                };
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return your condition;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. If I wanted to use Caliburn.Micro for doing this whould there be a better way to achieve this behavior? Sorry if this question makes no sense but I just started with MVVM/Caliburn and try get myself accustomed to that style.

Comment: I didn't know caliburn micro framework but it seems they use actions to achieve this task : http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/07/17/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-pt-3-all-about-actions.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to Bind your Button's Command property with an ICommand property in your viewmodel. In CanExecute method you can check if there are any validation errors. If yes, return False else return True. Button will automatically be activated / deactivated.

Comment: I currently have all the entities in an ObservableCollection. So my question is how can I have the method that disables the button called when something in this collection changes? And also if it is even a good idea to bind a grid in that way.

Comment: You do not have to disable the button when something is changed but you have to disable it when some validation error has occurred. Just bind the Button Command and implement the CanExecute method accordingly, you are done!